# object in "app_code" OK in masterpage, but not contentpage. nullReferenceException. httpcontext.items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, object, httpcontext

I have a C# file within "app_code" in my .net project. 
The file contains a namespace, "masterObjectNamespace", and a public class "masterObject".
during init of `masterObject()` I have the following 2 rows:

```
value1 = HttpContext.Current.Items["value"].ToString();
value2 = HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString();
```

From the masterpage I create an object of this class called master.

```
masterObject master = new masterObject();
```

Everything is OK!
BUT, when i try to create the an object within some of the contentpages, I get an

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

..
If I print the two rows within my contentpage, none of them are null, both contain some value.

Why is this happening to me? I create it the same way as in the masterpage.
The error is for the two rows that are lister above.

The `masterObject` is just to take care of session values and I would in the pages just call `master.ID()` to get the ID without any null-checking and stuff and `master.isAdmin()` to see if the admin is logged in.

This question is very blurry, I Guess it is because I don't know what is happening and how to explain it.

One alternative is that if it is possible to reach the object within masterpage so I don't have to create it once again wihtin content page, but I don't know how.

Thanks for reading!
Matte

Stack trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

masterObjectNamespace.masterObject..ctor() in \###\webvol6\m9\g2dlsc5plaz56r3\asdasd.com\public_html\App_Code\masterObject.cs:34

_Default..ctor() in \#####\webvol6\m9\g2dlsc5plaz56r3\asdasdasd.com\public_html\Default.aspx.cs:11

ASP.default_aspx..ctor() in App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.nudhzjvt.0.cs:0
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_default_aspx_cdcab7d2_nudhzjvt.Create_ASP_default_aspx() in App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.nudhzjvt.2.cs:0

System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +32

System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +119

System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33

System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40

System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +160

System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +93

System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

I dont know how to read this?!

**edit:**

i found that everything works for the content pages IF I before "protected void Page_load(...)" 
writes:

```
masterObject master;
```

and within page_load:

```
master = new masterObject();
```

Why is it like this for the content pages only?

Comment: get the stack trace of the `NullReferenceException` - where does the error occur?

Comment: Also, are you sure that objects are actually stored in the Items and Session collections using your "value" key? If not, you'll be attempting a ToString() on null - which will cause a NullReferenceException. Also, at what point in the page lifecycle are you attempting to create this object on your 'contentpages'?

Comment: Everything works while using this object within masterpage.. When I do the exactly the same thing withing a contentpage (which is in a sub folder) it does not work.

Comment: KazR: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    masterObject master = new masterObject();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {......